# How do we link multiple projects into the same web application

Tags: java, web-services

In a java based web-application that has multiple projects which are dependent on each other, where would normally we place configuration files like web.xml , log4j.properties and all? I am very new to web applications, but I pretty well know the package structure of a single project application. I am wondering how the application will look for the web.xml location and other configuration details  in a multi-project environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to build a project and add dependency on all other projects

if you are using Eclipse 
click right click on the master project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects [tab] 
here you can add other projects, good luck

Comment: So If I have to configure logging, the log4j.properties file should be configured separately for each project ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding multiple projects/modules have only one web based project and that require web.xml file, all other projects/module could be database/model or any other utility.