# How to inherit from a core project without making jar file?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

We need a solution using maven for project dependency management.

We have a core project which contains our base classes. We would like to develop another project that is dependent to our core project. The routine solution is to install core project as a .jar and add it as a dependency in child project's pom.xml file. Due to some managerial considerations, we are looking for a way to depend the child project to the core project directly ( like a project ordinary project dependency). Could we perform this using maven?

```
--core
  --front-core
    --front-draft
```

at the moment, we have solved it like this:
our core maven structure:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ir.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework.core</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
...
</project>
```

our front core maven structure :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ir.etick</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework.front</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework.core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
</project>
```

and in our front-draft:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ir.etick.front.draft</groupId>
    <artifactId>ir.etick.front.draft</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>ir.etick</groupId>
            <artifactId>framework.front</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

...
```

Comment: Can you show your child project pom.xml ?

Comment: I have updated my question with maven structure

Comment: what do you need to inherit if you don't want to make a jar?? It may be possible that you can create a pom project and reference it as dependency of type pom. This "Bill of Material" is then imported in your child project. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html and search for "BOM"

Comment: Could you please explain what "bar" it is ? Your link is the reference link and If you give me a quick solution it can be more helpful.Thanks anyway;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Madhi Shabani,

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your situation, but it sounds like you're asking whether you can declare `framework.core` as a direct dependency of `ir.etick.front.draft` even though it is also a dependency of `framework.front`.

If that's the question, then the answer yes, it is absolutely OK to have your dependency tree as follows:

**ir.etick.front.draft/pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ir.etick.front.draft</groupId>
<artifactId>ir.etick.front.draft</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>ir.etick</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework.front</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ir.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>framework.core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

I don't really understand your rationale for not wanting to package as a jar.

But if you must package the dependencies as type **war** instead, [see this guide](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2009/10/30/maven-dependency-on-jarwar-package/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you explain for me that what the maven's type of my parent project is ? I mean to say for example what type the framework.core and framework.front must be ? we don't want them as jar. can they be pom, war, bar or etc ? this is exactly what we want.

Comment: In Maven terms, framework.core and framework.front are not parent projects, they are regular projects just like ir.etic.front.draft. They are 3 siblings projects with dependency relationships between them.

Getting back to your question, framework.core and framework.front can be whatever packaging you want: pom, war, ear, jar, etc. The manner of packaging affects how you access the contents. In particular, if the framework contains Java code, then don't use pom packaging.

Comment: I think I got it!Let me try it and export my result ;)

Comment: @MahdiShabani, see edit of my post above for link to depending on war instead of jar (which frankly, is still pretty weird requirement).

Comment: For your clear understanding I can say that when we have some web projects (not jar) and we are using maven and we would like to have a multi-module project that some of them are dependent to each other, how can we have a single build for all of them. And now with the solution you had to me, I can attach all classes generated in my war files to my final war file that is aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you can solve it using maven, but you can solve it by project dependency.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700393/how-do-we-link-multiple-projects-into-the-same-web-application/26700486#26700486)

Comment: Thanks for reply.But I need maven structure.